# How can I install and configure windows 10 dll driver onto RP2 windows 10 IoT?

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot

I'd like to compile a run a code on RP2 but in order for me to do that i need to install the drivers for it on the RP2 and I'm not sure how to even approach that. I've installed WDK on VS 2015

Comment: There's an outside chance, albeit a slim one, that this might be possible. You will need a version of the DLL specifically compiled for the Raspberry Pi's ARM architecture. Do you have access to a precompiled ARM version, or access to any source code which could be recompiled for ARM?

Answer (score 2):

You need an **ARM** driver for Windows 10 **"IoT Core"** - if you don't have the **complete** source code for it you **must** ask the hardware manufacturer for such a driver (except if you like reverse-engineering for hundreds of hours).

A "normal" Windows 10 "Home" or "Professional" (x64- or x86-only) driver **will not work** .